# MariaDB Group by Slower than MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb

This query returns in 2.5s on MySQL and 13.5s on MariaDB.
It's a large table, so I'm only selecting a small range of data 2 million rows.

I've tried on multiple servers and results always roughly the same, what am I missing?

Why would MariaDB be so much slower?

```
    SELECT yyyymmdd,
           customer_id,
           product_id,
           sum(qty),
           sum(value)
    FROM large_table
    WHERE yyyymmdd >= 20180101
      AND yyyymmdd < 20180201
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ORDER BY NULL
```

Note: I've tried indexing different combinations etc but nothing made much of a difference.

**Explain Mysql:**

[image: mysql explain]

**Explain Mariadb:**

[image: mariadb explain]

Comment: can you include explain plans for both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the SQL_BIG_RESULT in the select query has sorted it out, I now get roughly the same response times.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#SQL_BIG_RESULT

Also, increasing tmp_table_size & max_heap_table_size

Comment: Facing similar issue on my InnoDB table with 600K+ rows, while running a small query: `Select count(*) from products Where catId=90 group by colorName;` response coming in 50 seconds on 8Core CPU with 32 GB RAM. Trying SQL_BIG_RESULT returns response in 40 sec.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the performance difference between MySQL and MariaDB, but I can suggest the following index which, if used, might improve performance on both databases:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON large_table (yyyymmdd, customer_id, product_id);
```

This index covers the entire `WHERE` clause, and should be a candidate for use assuming your date range is fairly specific.

Comment: Facing similar issue on my InnoDB table with 600K+ rows, while running a small query: `Select count(*) from products Where catId=90 group by colorName;` response coming in 50 seconds on 8Core CPU with 32 GB RAM. Trying SQL_BIG_RESULT returns response in 40 sec. Color column has been defined as indexed but it's cardinality is very low.